NSTableView doesn't move row down when using NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap
I have several NSTableView instances whose draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle is set to NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap.
The delegate method tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation: returns NSDragOperationMove.
When I drag a row upward, all the rows that are above the dragged row and below the destination move down, to create the "gap", except the row just above the dragged row. This one never moves down. So the next row (which moves down as it should), overlap with the row that doesn't move down.
(Moving a row downwards works as it should.)
This has been happening on all macOS version I've tested (11 to 15) and in all table views that I tested (even in a test project that contains nothing but the table in a window).
What am I doing wrong?

It looks like a bug in NSTableView to me. Try a different Row Size Style in the XIB/Storyboard.

Thanks. Most row size styles fix the issue, except "custom" and "match canvas".

But this creates a new problem. dragImageForRowsWithIndexes: returns a blank image when I call this method within tableView:draggingSession:willBeginAtPoint:forRowIndexes:. This returns the correct image of the row when the row size style is "custom".
